# extract excel vba macros from excel files programatically

Tags: vba, excel

I have many excel macros I have written over the years and I would like to compile them into one document or module containing the functions I most frequently use (written very modular and reusable by others).

Anyone know how to programatically access the excel vba modules using vba or some other automation?

Answer (score 2):

The topic is well-covered here:

[Pearson's Programming The VBA Editor](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx)

Comment: +1. OP would've found this if he'd bothered to spend 5 mins on google. :) This solution works, and with minor modifications can be applicable to PPT and Word, too.

Comment: Although the code needs some mods to extract all components, plus updated to handle multiple workbooks.

Answer (score 2):

This code

- Opens all `xlsm` files in a directory specififed by `StrDir` (*C:\temp* in this example)
- Exports each code component to a second directory specified by `StrDir2` (*C:\mycode*) if there is at least one line of code in that module

*code*

```
Sub GetCode()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim VBProj
Dim VBComp
Dim StrDir As String
Dim StrDir2 As String
Dim StrFile As String

StrDir = "c:\temp\"
StrDir2 = "c:\mycode\"

If Len(Dir(StrDir2, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir StrDir2
StrFile = Dir(StrDir & "*.xlsm")

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(StrDir & StrFile, False)
    Set VBProj = WB.VBProject
        For Each VBComp In VBProj.vbcomponents
            If VBComp.codemodule.countoflines > 0 Then VBComp.Export StrDir2 & StrFile & "_" & VBComp.Name & ".txt"
        Next
    WB.Close False
StrFile = Dir
Loop

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. Change the search to look for *.xls* files to cater for these types as well

Comment: when you export a module it shows the following text "Attribute VB_Name = "Module1". IS there a way to just get the text from each of the modules and store it in a VARIABLE?. I.e. I don't want to write one procedure to collate all excel macros I have written to TXT files, and then another to parse the data in the text files?

Comment: You could always ask that as a separate question, given you don't appear to have written anything to solve your question so far...

Comment: it's hard to justify doing that, when there is a limit to how frequently you can ask questions. I.e. at the computer for a short time, you can't ask all your questions then because you are limited to 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of brettdj's code for plodding through word documents.  The idea is to use something like WinMerge to compare successive versions afterwards.

This version runs in Excel, but operates on Word documents.  (Excel is a far better and a more permissive VBA environment than Word).  Be sure to have a reference of "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" (or whatever version you have) in your project references.

The other difference is that in this example, it expects a clean "Dump" subdirectory then creates subdirectories for every set of files generated from every document.  Note there are also .frm files which not entirely readable with casual text editors.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetCode()
    Dim Doc As Word.Document
    Dim VBProj
    Dim VBComp
    Dim dir1 As String: dir1 = "C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\"
    Dim dir2 As String: dir2 = "C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\Dump\"
    Dim dir3 As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim fn As String
    Dim n As String

    If Len(Dir(dir2, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir dir2
    file = Dir(dir1 & "*.dotm")
    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Application.EnableEvents = False

    Do While Len(file) > 0
        Set Doc = Word.Documents.Open(dir1 & file, False)
        Set VBProj = Doc.VBProject
            For Each VBComp In VBProj.vbcomponents
                If VBComp.codemodule.countoflines > 0 Then
                    dir3 = dir2 & Replace(file, ".dotm", "") ' new subdirectory, get rid of .dotm
                    On Error Resume Next
                    MkDir dir3
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    n = VBComp.Name
                    fn = dir3 & "\" & n & ".txt"  ' the actual file name
                    VBComp.Export fn  ' exports the code and (pesky) .frx files
                End If
            Next
        Doc.Close False
    file = Dir
    Loop

    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ' Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```